# Password recovery with forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, password-recovery

I am a beginner of asp.net. I currently have a login page with forgot password link button on the bottom of the screen. I am also using forms authentication to prevent an unauthorized user from accessing the other pages. The authentication seems to be working fine except for one thing.
How do I retrieve my password from the user list?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to store or retrieve the original password for security reasons - asp.net should be storing a hash of the original password in your data store. When a user enters their password again, the configured hashing algorithm should hash it to the same value as before and it matches the stored hash on the backend to authenticate.

See also [Asp.net MVC - How to hash password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802164/asp-net-mvc-how-to-hash-password) for more background.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using form-based authentication. For example:
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="frmPanel" path="/admin" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="1440">
          <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
            <user name="admin" password="admin1"/>
            <user name="user" password="user2"/>
          </credentials>
        </forms>
      </authentication>