# how can i encrypt Password in MVC5 C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

where should i perform coding to encrypt password??
controller or view

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes:new{@class="control-label col-md-2" })

    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, 
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "password" } })

    </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure of what you want to achieve. Can you explain further?

Comment: Options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802164/asp-net-mvc-how-to-hash-password

Comment: i have a form in which i am entering password

Comment: Submit the form, pass the password to the controller, hash it, forget the password forever, save the hash, done.

Comment: problem is how to pass the password to controller?? @T.Jung

Comment: @GSerg is right. If your are using the [UserManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290(v=vs.108).aspx) you can do: `UserManager.createAsync(yourApplicationUser, model.Password)`  . The Usermanager saves the User to your DB with the username and the hashed password.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you site. If you are using a secure connection you can just hash the password in the controller (or wherever in the server code).

If you are using a not secure connection, I suggest to read this thread: https://forums.asp.net/t/2006037.aspx?Password+is+still+in+plain+text

Here the suggestion is to hash the password from the textbox, store it in an hidden field in the form and send the hidden field to the server instead of the password field.